# JProgressBar won't perform updates on UI used through SwingWorker<T, R>

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, future, event-dispatch-thread

I'm using SwingWorker<T, R> for a while now to handle updates on EDT and recently faced a situation where this approach won't help to continue the task. here is my code and scenario.

My code contains several abstractions to handle the flow correctly

1. AbstractOperationsManager - contains common code for each Operations manager
2. Initializer - a concrete implementation of operation manager in the flow
3. JProgressBarConsumer - a wrapper for abstracting routines related to UI from operations manager implementation
4. OperationObserver - handling operation event updates
5. OperationBroker - a mediator between OperationManager and OperationObserver

```
package org.app.core.api;

import java.util.Iterator;
import ...

public abstract class AbstractOperationManager extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private OperationBroker broker;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractOperationManager.class);
    private final List<UIConsumer> uiconsumer;
    private volatile boolean cancelled;

    public AbstractOperationManager() {
        super();
        this.uiconsumer = new LinkedList<>();
        this.cancelled = false;
    }

    public abstract void init(OperationBroker broker);

    public void addOperationsBroker(OperationBroker broker) {
        this.broker = broker;
    }

    public void addUIConsumer(UIConsumer consumer) {
        this.uiconsumer.add(consumer);
    }

    /**
     * customized method to inform observers of implicit cancellation of
     * operations because of either exception or for intentional purposes
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isOperationCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {
        while (true) {
            OperationEvent latestE = this.broker.getObserver().getLatestEvent();

            if (latestE.getOperationType().equals(Operation.OPERATION_TYPE.TERMINATE)) {
                OperationTerminationEvent ote = (OperationTerminationEvent) latestE;
                if (ote.isExecThrown()) {
                    //log for exception
                    cancel(true);
                    cancelled = true;
                }
                break;
            } else if (latestE.getOperationType().equals(Operation.OPERATION_TYPE.LOG)) {
                //perform logging operations

            } else {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> this.uiconsumer
                                .forEach(consumer-> consumer
                                                .consumeEvent(latestE)));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        publish();
        broker.operate();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The key execution point which results in updating the GUI is the iterator in `uiconsumer`. It's an abstraction for a specific UI component to handle its flow and in this case, `JProgressBar`.

One reason for adding a bogus `publish()` call is to trigger the **chunk processing** and it is the broker who performs the operations and supplies the updates for the individual operations carried out.

```
package org.app.util;

import org.app.core.api.OperationEvent;
import org.app.core.api.OperationObserver;

public class SystemOperationObserver implements OperationObserver {

    private OperationEvent event;

    @Override
    public void notifyObserver(OperationEvent event) {
        try {
            eventQueue.put(event);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int queuedCount() {
        return eventQueue.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OperationEvent getLatestEvent() {
        OperationEvent event = null;
        try {
            event = eventQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

OperationObserver is the event supplier which contains a `LinkedBlockingQueue<T>` for carrying out updates from several threads in OperationManager. Each and every operation holds access to this **observer**

```
package org.app.views.components;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import ...

public class JProgressBarConsumer implements UIConsumer {

    private JProgressBar progress;
    private Predicate<OperationEvent> predicate;

    public JProgressBarConsumer(JProgressBar progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        this.progress.setStringPainted(true);
        this.progress.setValue(0);
    }

    private boolean filterEvent(OperationEvent event) {
        if (this.predicate != null) {
            return this.predicate.test(event);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void on(Predicate<OperationEvent> eventFilter) {
        this.predicate = eventFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void consumeEvent(OperationEvent event) {
        boolean shouldContinue = filterEvent(event);
        if (shouldContinue) {
            int currentProgress = this.progress.getValue();
            int percentage = (int) event.getPercentage() + currentProgress;
            this.progress.setValue(percentage);     
            this.progress.repaint();
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package org.app.util;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import ...

public class Initializer extends AbstractOperationManager {

    private CountDownLatch hook;

    public Initializer() {
        super();
        hook = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(OperationBroker broker) {
        addOperationsBroker(broker);
    }

    public CountDownLatch getHook() {
        return hook;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        boolean isOpcancelled = this.isOperationCancelled();
        if (!isOpcancelled) {
            hook.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Scenario

The code should update the JProgressBar visually but what it really does is update only the last event progress (which the value is 100) and ignore the rest.

One reason could be that there should be a greater interval between UI events consumed by the `JProgressBarConsumer` `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(60);`

Another reason could be the code block the EDT between the operations because of `LinkedBlockingQueue` behavior until the Latch Release the control

Questions

- What could really be the cause of not updating JPogressBar?
- The `cancel(true)` in AbstractOperationsManager isn't working properly (It's a problem with `Future` of course but please shed some light on that) and had to introduce a breaker manually. I did tons of research to understand the `Future` behavior and its **cancellation** process and still no luck.

Comment: This `while (true) {`, inside `process` is your core problem.  `process` is executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, so your `while (true)` will block the EDT and nothing will ever get updated, until you some how magically break out of it.  This work should be done in `doBackground` and `publish`/`process` should be used to "publish" updates that are "processed" on the EDT. Additional `while(true)` is really bad, make the effort to actually design a reasonable exit condition to the loop

Comment: If you find yourself using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` with a `SwingWorker`, then you're using it wrong

Comment: yes @MadProgrammer I thought that too when I design the api but that approach brings me further doubts when dealing with the ``` List<T> chunks ``` in process method. the problem is that sometimes the chunks will be lost because of the rate events produced and I had to define manually the ``` Thread.sleep(x) ``` to make it work. it's a trial and error method which I really like to avoid.

Comment: If you have a look at [the JavaDocs for `SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) it actually demonstrates how you can use it with `JProgressBar`, but, admittedly, you need to implement a `PropertyChangeListener` to catch the progress events.  The `chuncks` are, generally, any data "chuncks" you might want synched with the UI, you could, technically just `publish` progress values and in `process` get the last `chunck` and update the progress bar accordingly

Comment: *"the problem is that sometimes the chunks will be lost because of the rate events produced"* - You'd probably have the same issue with `EventQueue.invokeLater` as you're starving the EDT (the "processing" loop is running too fast/to often).  `Thread.yield` might help. Equally, you could also consider something like [Coalescing (combining) high frequency events to improve performance](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-swing/coalesce-events.html)